# Change Packages

Tags: miktex2.9

Is it possible to change packages that are installed by miktex?
If I install a package manually, the .sty and .def files are textfiles and changeable. I thought it would be exactly like that, if miktex installs the package by itself. But I can't find the files. Are they binary files? Or am I only blind and don't see them?

Comment: The packages MikTeX installs are just like that. They are mostly plain-text `.sty`, `.tex` and `.def` files. On my machine most packages live in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`, but if you have a single-user install yours might be in `C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9`. You can see where the packages go in the MikTeX Console in the *Packages* tab. But please note that **it is *extremely* bad practice to edit files installed by your TeX distribution in place**. You can edit renamed copies of those files if you like, but changing the originals just asks for trouble.

Comment: The *Settings > Directories* tab in the MikTeX Console also has some info. As for why it is bad practice to manually edit distribution-installed and -controlled files: The files may be overwritten by updates or other changes and your modifications get lost. You may also want to cooperate with other people, ask questions here or just compile your document on a different system. If your document relies on your private modifications to an otherwise public package that can lead to incompatibilities and different results on different systems. Something LaTeX tries to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you. It was not C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9. In my case it was the C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Yes you are right it is not good practice to do that. I only want to change the format of a file to check if it is nicer. If it is, I will create a fork of this package and will suggest the changes to the creator of the package.

Comment: The easy way to find where the package is located is to compile a small tex program that uses the package.  The log file will tell you *exactly* where it found it.  If you then go there and, for example, delete the `.sty` file, and recompile, MikTeX will be forced to reinstall the package.  This is one way to bring packages up to date.  The other method is using the package manager to uninstall and reinstall packages.

Comment: You can also find the location of a `.sty` file by calling `kpsewhich filename.sty` in the command line.

Comment: If you want (really, really need) edited versions of common distributed packages, the best approach is to create your version with a different name, e.g., `<package-MYNAME>` and stored that version in your local TeX folder (texmf). And keep very well noted you did this modification (and what you did). @moewe's answer pretty much summarize the headaches you are susceptible when editing the main folder and keeping the same name. You will forget what you did, will not have the same results as your pairs, basically you will be speak a foreign language.

Answer (score -1):

Because of moewe I found the directory, where the packages are stored. Like moewe pointed out, you can find it in the miktex console in tab Packages.[image]

Comment: The potential uh-oh to this approach is that if you keep a locally changed version around in your search path (see MikTeX console, Settings, Directories), your local version may be loaded before the official MikTeX version.  In that case, updating the official version of the package would still never make it into your document. The more reliable method is given in my 2019 comment, which is to compile a tiny document that loads the package of interest.  The .log file will tell you exactly which copy of the sty file it found and used.